# Long delay before running unit tests in Visual Studio 2012 Update 4

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2012

I've tried unit testing within VS2012 for the first time and I'm using VS2012 update 4. When I click "Run All" in the Test Explorer window, it takes about 5 to 10 seconds for the tests to start running. I foud this: [Visual studio 2012 slow unit testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13541411/visual-studio-2012-slow-unit-testing) but it didn't fix it. Other fixes I've read suggest getting the newest version of VS2012 but I believe I have that. Anything else I could try?

Edit: I also tried uninstalling VS 2010 as I read that might be a cause.

Side question: Is there a way to stop VS from returning to the output window every time I click "Run All" for tests? This is just weird. I of course want to see the test results so I want to remain on the Test Explorer window.

Code just in case:

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using System;
using MyProject;

namespace MyProjectTest
{
    [TestClass]
    public class FooTest
    {
        private Bar _bar;

        [TestInitialize]
        public void TestInitialize()
        {
        }

        [TestCleanup]
        public void TestCleanup()
        {
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void Baz_AllLefts_5()
        {
            Assert.IsTrue(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You might be interested in http://TestDriven.Net - it adds a right-click test runner that allows you to stay in your main window when running tests.

Comment: TD.net exposes commands so you can bind keystrokes to it. Really nice.. and fast.