# Debugging Unit Test is very slow in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio

When I debug non unit tests, I have no issues with debugging. If I debug unit tests, I have a start up time > 10 seconds due to fact that Visual Studio tries to load symbols although I've disabled accessing symbol servers in the Debug Settings.

What might be the issue here? I've found 
[this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13541411/visual-studio-2012-slow-unit-testing) but it does not seem to fit to my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, for me Visual Studio 2013 Update 2 RC has solved this issue